# Lıve XML to HTML Table when new element added

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, xml

I have json and ajax code for xml data every second.Its  working cool.When i added xml element its added to html table automaticly.My problem is when i call function every 3 second the html page refresh effect because new elements adding to table so its annoying view refresh page every 3 second.So i want to add when new element added code will work 1 time and add new td element to table.Its customer info screen at self service cafe program so when seller add a new item at his program it will show at customer monitor.
Thx.Sorry for my bad eng.

```
<script>

 $(document).ready(function() {
        //
       
            setInterval(function() {
            $('#tableBody').empty();       
            //ajax call to load XML and parse it
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '01.xml',          
                dataType: 'xml',    
                success: function(xml) {
                   
                    $(xml).find('dsname').each(function() {
                        
                  
                        $('#tableBody').append(
                            '<tr>' +
                                '<td>' +
                                    $(this).find('STOKADI').text() + '</td> ' +
                                '<td>' +
                                    $(this).find('BORC').text() +'₺'+ '</td> ' +
                                
                            '</tr>');
                    });
                }
            });
             }, 3000);
        });

    
</script>





        
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>         
        <script type="text/javascript">
      
            
  </script>
```

My xml data when sellers try to sell something:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>

    <NewDataSet>
      <dsname>
        <SIRANO>-1</SIRANO>
        <STOKKODU>ESP04</STOKKODU>
        <STOKADI>AMERİCANO</STOKADI>
        <DIP_ISKONTO_TUTARI>0.00</DIP_ISKONTO_TUTARI>
        <BORC>1.00</BORC>
        <MIKTAR>1.000</MIKTAR>
        <FIYAT>1.0000</FIYAT>
        <ISKONTO_TUTARI>0.00</ISKONTO_TUTARI>
        <TUTAR>1.00</TUTAR>
        <BARKOD>810000000009</BARKOD>
        <FIYAT_TL>1.0000</FIYAT_TL>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT1>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT1>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT2>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT2>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT3>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT3>
        <PERAKENDE_DOVIZ>TL</PERAKENDE_DOVIZ>
        <PERAKENDE_FIYAT>0</PERAKENDE_FIYAT>
        <KALAN>0</KALAN>
        <OKUNAN_BARKOD>ESP04</OKUNAN_BARKOD>
        <BIRIM_KODU>AD</BIRIM_KODU>
        <KDV_TUTARI>0.00</KDV_TUTARI>
      </dsname>
      <dsname>
        <SIRANO>-2</SIRANO>
        <STOKKODU>ESP09</STOKKODU>
        <STOKADI>CAPPUCCİNO</STOKADI>
        <DIP_ISKONTO_TUTARI>0.00</DIP_ISKONTO_TUTARI>
        <BORC>1.00</BORC>
        <MIKTAR>1.000</MIKTAR>
        <FIYAT>1.0000</FIYAT>
        <ISKONTO_TUTARI>0.00</ISKONTO_TUTARI>
        <TUTAR>1.00</TUTAR>
        <BARKOD>810000000014</BARKOD>
        <FIYAT_TL>1.0000</FIYAT_TL>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT1>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT1>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT2>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT2>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT3>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT3>
        <PERAKENDE_DOVIZ>TL</PERAKENDE_DOVIZ>
        <PERAKENDE_FIYAT>0</PERAKENDE_FIYAT>
        <KALAN>0</KALAN>
        <OKUNAN_BARKOD>ESP09</OKUNAN_BARKOD>
        <BIRIM_KODU>AD</BIRIM_KODU>
        <KDV_TUTARI>0.00</KDV_TUTARI>
      </dsname>
      <dsname>
        <SIRANO>-3</SIRANO>
        <STOKKODU>ESP08</STOKKODU>
        <STOKADI>CARAMEL MACCHİATO</STOKADI>
        <DIP_ISKONTO_TUTARI>0.00</DIP_ISKONTO_TUTARI>
        <BORC>1.00</BORC>
        <MIKTAR>1.000</MIKTAR>
        <FIYAT>1.0000</FIYAT>
        <ISKONTO_TUTARI>0.00</ISKONTO_TUTARI>
        <TUTAR>1.00</TUTAR>
        <BARKOD>810000000013</BARKOD>
        <FIYAT_TL>1.0000</FIYAT_TL>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT1>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT1>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT2>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT2>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT3>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT3>
        <PERAKENDE_DOVIZ>TL</PERAKENDE_DOVIZ>
        <PERAKENDE_FIYAT>0</PERAKENDE_FIYAT>
        <KALAN>0</KALAN>
        <OKUNAN_BARKOD>ESP08</OKUNAN_BARKOD>
        <BIRIM_KODU>AD</BIRIM_KODU>
        <KDV_TUTARI>0.00</KDV_TUTARI>
      </dsname>
      <dsname>
        <SIRANO>-4</SIRANO>
        <STOKKODU>ESP12</STOKKODU>
        <STOKADI>CHAİ TEA LATTE</STOKADI>
        <DIP_ISKONTO_TUTARI>0.00</DIP_ISKONTO_TUTARI>
        <BORC>1.00</BORC>
        <MIKTAR>1.000</MIKTAR>
        <FIYAT>1.0000</FIYAT>
        <ISKONTO_TUTARI>0.00</ISKONTO_TUTARI>
        <TUTAR>1.00</TUTAR>
        <BARKOD>810000000017</BARKOD>
        <FIYAT_TL>1.0000</FIYAT_TL>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT1>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT1>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT2>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT2>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT3>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT3>
        <PERAKENDE_DOVIZ>TL</PERAKENDE_DOVIZ>
        <PERAKENDE_FIYAT>0</PERAKENDE_FIYAT>
        <KALAN>0</KALAN>
        <OKUNAN_BARKOD>ESP12</OKUNAN_BARKOD>
        <BIRIM_KODU>AD</BIRIM_KODU>
        <KDV_TUTARI>0.00</KDV_TUTARI>
      </dsname>
      <dsname>
        <SIRANO>-5</SIRANO>
        <STOKKODU>ESP12</STOKKODU>
        <STOKADI>CHAİ TEA LATTE</STOKADI>
        <DIP_ISKONTO_TUTARI>0.00</DIP_ISKONTO_TUTARI>
        <BORC>1.00</BORC>
        <MIKTAR>1.000</MIKTAR>
        <FIYAT>1.0000</FIYAT>
        <ISKONTO_TUTARI>0.00</ISKONTO_TUTARI>
        <TUTAR>1.00</TUTAR>
        <BARKOD>810000000017</BARKOD>
        <FIYAT_TL>1.0000</FIYAT_TL>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT1>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT1>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT2>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT2>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT3>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT3>
        <PERAKENDE_DOVIZ>TL</PERAKENDE_DOVIZ>
        <PERAKENDE_FIYAT>0</PERAKENDE_FIYAT>
        <KALAN>0</KALAN>
        <OKUNAN_BARKOD>ESP12</OKUNAN_BARKOD>
        <BIRIM_KODU>AD</BIRIM_KODU>
        <KDV_TUTARI>0.00</KDV_TUTARI>
      </dsname>
      <dsname>
        <SIRANO>-6</SIRANO>
        <STOKKODU>ESP04</STOKKODU>
        <STOKADI>AMERİCANO</STOKADI>
        <DIP_ISKONTO_TUTARI>0.00</DIP_ISKONTO_TUTARI>
        <BORC>1.00</BORC>
        <MIKTAR>1.000</MIKTAR>
        <FIYAT>1.0000</FIYAT>
        <ISKONTO_TUTARI>0.00</ISKONTO_TUTARI>
        <TUTAR>1.00</TUTAR>
        <BARKOD>810000000009</BARKOD>
        <FIYAT_TL>1.0000</FIYAT_TL>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT1>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT1>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT2>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT2>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT3>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT3>
        <PERAKENDE_DOVIZ>TL</PERAKENDE_DOVIZ>
        <PERAKENDE_FIYAT>0</PERAKENDE_FIYAT>
        <KALAN>0</KALAN>
        <OKUNAN_BARKOD>ESP04</OKUNAN_BARKOD>
        <BIRIM_KODU>AD</BIRIM_KODU>
        <KDV_TUTARI>0.00</KDV_TUTARI>
      </dsname>
      <dsname>
        <SIRANO>-7</SIRANO>
        <STOKKODU>ESP09</STOKKODU>
        <STOKADI>CAPPUCCİNO</STOKADI>
        <DIP_ISKONTO_TUTARI>0.00</DIP_ISKONTO_TUTARI>
        <BORC>1.00</BORC>
        <MIKTAR>1.000</MIKTAR>
        <FIYAT>1.0000</FIYAT>
        <ISKONTO_TUTARI>0.00</ISKONTO_TUTARI>
        <TUTAR>1.00</TUTAR>
        <BARKOD>810000000014</BARKOD>
        <FIYAT_TL>1.0000</FIYAT_TL>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT1>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT1>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT2>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT2>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT3>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT3>
        <PERAKENDE_DOVIZ>TL</PERAKENDE_DOVIZ>
        <PERAKENDE_FIYAT>0</PERAKENDE_FIYAT>
        <KALAN>0</KALAN>
        <OKUNAN_BARKOD>ESP09</OKUNAN_BARKOD>
        <BIRIM_KODU>AD</BIRIM_KODU>
        <KDV_TUTARI>0.00</KDV_TUTARI>
      </dsname>
      <dsname>
        <SIRANO>-8</SIRANO>
        <STOKKODU>ESP08</STOKKODU>
        <STOKADI>CARAMEL MACCHİATO</STOKADI>
        <DIP_ISKONTO_TUTARI>0.00</DIP_ISKONTO_TUTARI>
        <BORC>1.00</BORC>
        <MIKTAR>1.000</MIKTAR>
        <FIYAT>1.0000</FIYAT>
        <ISKONTO_TUTARI>0.00</ISKONTO_TUTARI>
        <TUTAR>1.00</TUTAR>
        <BARKOD>810000000013</BARKOD>
        <FIYAT_TL>1.0000</FIYAT_TL>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT1>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT1>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT2>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT2>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT3>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT3>
        <PERAKENDE_DOVIZ>TL</PERAKENDE_DOVIZ>
        <PERAKENDE_FIYAT>0</PERAKENDE_FIYAT>
        <KALAN>0</KALAN>
        <OKUNAN_BARKOD>ESP08</OKUNAN_BARKOD>
        <BIRIM_KODU>AD</BIRIM_KODU>
        <KDV_TUTARI>0.00</KDV_TUTARI>
      </dsname>
      <dsname>
        <SIRANO>-9</SIRANO>
        <STOKKODU>ESP12</STOKKODU>
        <STOKADI>CHAİ TEA LATTE</STOKADI>
        <DIP_ISKONTO_TUTARI>0.00</DIP_ISKONTO_TUTARI>
        <BORC>1.00</BORC>
        <MIKTAR>1.000</MIKTAR>
        <FIYAT>1.0000</FIYAT>
        <ISKONTO_TUTARI>0.00</ISKONTO_TUTARI>
        <TUTAR>1.00</TUTAR>
        <BARKOD>810000000017</BARKOD>
        <FIYAT_TL>1.0000</FIYAT_TL>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT1>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT1>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT2>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT2>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT3>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT3>
        <PERAKENDE_DOVIZ>TL</PERAKENDE_DOVIZ>
        <PERAKENDE_FIYAT>0</PERAKENDE_FIYAT>
        <KALAN>0</KALAN>
        <OKUNAN_BARKOD>ESP12</OKUNAN_BARKOD>
        <BIRIM_KODU>AD</BIRIM_KODU>
        <KDV_TUTARI>0.00</KDV_TUTARI>
      </dsname>
     
    </NewDataSet>
```

My xml data when sell menu is empty:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
    
        <NewDataSet>
```

I want to check when new element added at XML then i want to run the function.

Edit my page for nick:

```
   <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Customer Screen</title>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     <link href="dist/css/pageDesign.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
    <body>
<script>


 $(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    //ajax call to load XML and parse it
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '01.xml',          
      dataType: 'xml',    
      success: function(xml) {
      
        updateTable(xml)
        updateNeeded(xml)
      }
    });
  }, 3000);
});

const updateNeeded = (xml) => {
  const xmlValues = $(xml).find('dsname stokadi').map(function() {
    return $(this).text()
  }).get()
  const tableValues = $('#tableBody .stokadi').map(function() {
    return $(this).text()
  }).get()
  return xmlValues.length != tableValues.length ||
    !xmlValues.every((v, i) => v === tableValues[i])
}

const updateTable = (xml) => {
  if (updateNeeded(xml)) {
    $('#tableBody').empty()
    $(xml).find('dsname').each(function() {
      const stokadi = $(this).find('STOKADI').text()
      const borc = $(this).find('BORC').text()
      $('#tableBody').append(
        `<tr><td class="stokadi">${stokadi}</td><td class="borc">${borc}₺</td></tr>`)
    })
  }
}


    
</script>





        
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>         
        <script type="text/javascript">
      
            
  </script> 


   
    <table class='table table-bordered table-striped datatable'>
      <thead style='background:#999900;'>
        <tr>
          <th>SIRA</th>
          <th>ÜRÜN</th>
          <th>FİYAT</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="tableBody">
        
      </tbody>
    
    </table>
   <img  src="1.png"
  
     style="width: 250px; height: 250px; margin-left: 800px">
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Sorry, I've tried everything I can.

Comment: Its mean my code edit is true right ?

Comment: You don't need the call to `updateNeeded` inside `document.ready` but otherwise yes.

Comment: You might want to try some debugging prints inside your environment (e.g. on `xmlValues`, `tableValues` `stokadi` and `borc`, perhaps something will show up

Comment: i try at console log but no data showing at xmlvalues tablevalues stokadi and borc.Propably i can't do this at 5 hours so my work going to trash.

Comment: Is there anything in `xml`? as long as it was in the format in your question then `xmlValues` should have something in it.

Comment: I check step by step xmlvalues is empty.And if (updateNeeded(xml)) condution never work

Comment: I edited your XML into my answer and it seems to work fine there... try running the snippet

Comment: propably your code is ok i am doing something wrong when i try to add to my page.ı am adding all my page at last edit.

Comment: I wish İ can give you connection but i guess its illegal for stackeroverflow

Comment: `Sorry for my bad eng.` ... your english is ok ... there should always be a space between sentences ( after a period )

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this is to add classes to the `stokadi` and `borc` table cells and then check whether each value in the xml is already in the table before adding it

```js
const updateNeeded = (xml) => {
  const xmlValues = $(xml).find('dsname stokadi').map(function() {
    return $(this).text()
  }).get()
  const tableValues = $('#tableBody .stokadi').map(function() {
    return $(this).text()
  }).get()
  return xmlValues.length != tableValues.length ||
    !xmlValues.every((v, i) => v === tableValues[i])
}

const updateTable = (xml) => {
  if (updateNeeded(xml)) {
    $('#tableBody').empty()
    $(xml).find('dsname').each(function() {
      const stokadi = $(this).find('STOKADI').text()
      const borc = $(this).find('BORC').text()
      $('#tableBody').append(
        `<tr><td class="stokadi">${stokadi}</td><td class="borc">${borc}₺</td></tr>`)
    })
  }
}

let xml = `<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>

    <NewDataSet>
      <dsname>
        <SIRANO>-1</SIRANO>
        <STOKKODU>ESP04</STOKKODU>
        <STOKADI>AMERİCANO</STOKADI>
        <DIP_ISKONTO_TUTARI>0.00</DIP_ISKONTO_TUTARI>
        <BORC>1.00</BORC>
        <MIKTAR>1.000</MIKTAR>
        <FIYAT>1.0000</FIYAT>
        <ISKONTO_TUTARI>0.00</ISKONTO_TUTARI>
        <TUTAR>1.00</TUTAR>
        <BARKOD>810000000009</BARKOD>
        <FIYAT_TL>1.0000</FIYAT_TL>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT1>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT1>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT2>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT2>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT3>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT3>
        <PERAKENDE_DOVIZ>TL</PERAKENDE_DOVIZ>
        <PERAKENDE_FIYAT>0</PERAKENDE_FIYAT>
        <KALAN>0</KALAN>
        <OKUNAN_BARKOD>ESP04</OKUNAN_BARKOD>
        <BIRIM_KODU>AD</BIRIM_KODU>
        <KDV_TUTARI>0.00</KDV_TUTARI>
      </dsname>
      <dsname>
        <SIRANO>-2</SIRANO>
        <STOKKODU>ESP09</STOKKODU>
        <STOKADI>CAPPUCCİNO</STOKADI>
        <DIP_ISKONTO_TUTARI>0.00</DIP_ISKONTO_TUTARI>
        <BORC>1.00</BORC>
        <MIKTAR>1.000</MIKTAR>
        <FIYAT>1.0000</FIYAT>
        <ISKONTO_TUTARI>0.00</ISKONTO_TUTARI>
        <TUTAR>1.00</TUTAR>
        <BARKOD>810000000014</BARKOD>
        <FIYAT_TL>1.0000</FIYAT_TL>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT1>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT1>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT2>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT2>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT3>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT3>
        <PERAKENDE_DOVIZ>TL</PERAKENDE_DOVIZ>
        <PERAKENDE_FIYAT>0</PERAKENDE_FIYAT>
        <KALAN>0</KALAN>
        <OKUNAN_BARKOD>ESP09</OKUNAN_BARKOD>
        <BIRIM_KODU>AD</BIRIM_KODU>
        <KDV_TUTARI>0.00</KDV_TUTARI>
      </dsname>
      <dsname>
        <SIRANO>-3</SIRANO>
        <STOKKODU>ESP08</STOKKODU>
        <STOKADI>CARAMEL MACCHİATO</STOKADI>
        <DIP_ISKONTO_TUTARI>0.00</DIP_ISKONTO_TUTARI>
        <BORC>1.00</BORC>
        <MIKTAR>1.000</MIKTAR>
        <FIYAT>1.0000</FIYAT>
        <ISKONTO_TUTARI>0.00</ISKONTO_TUTARI>
        <TUTAR>1.00</TUTAR>
        <BARKOD>810000000013</BARKOD>
        <FIYAT_TL>1.0000</FIYAT_TL>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT1>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT1>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT2>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT2>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT3>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT3>
        <PERAKENDE_DOVIZ>TL</PERAKENDE_DOVIZ>
        <PERAKENDE_FIYAT>0</PERAKENDE_FIYAT>
        <KALAN>0</KALAN>
        <OKUNAN_BARKOD>ESP08</OKUNAN_BARKOD>
        <BIRIM_KODU>AD</BIRIM_KODU>
        <KDV_TUTARI>0.00</KDV_TUTARI>
      </dsname>
      <dsname>
        <SIRANO>-4</SIRANO>
        <STOKKODU>ESP12</STOKKODU>
        <STOKADI>CHAİ TEA LATTE</STOKADI>
        <DIP_ISKONTO_TUTARI>0.00</DIP_ISKONTO_TUTARI>
        <BORC>1.00</BORC>
        <MIKTAR>1.000</MIKTAR>
        <FIYAT>1.0000</FIYAT>
        <ISKONTO_TUTARI>0.00</ISKONTO_TUTARI>
        <TUTAR>1.00</TUTAR>
        <BARKOD>810000000017</BARKOD>
        <FIYAT_TL>1.0000</FIYAT_TL>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT1>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT1>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT2>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT2>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT3>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT3>
        <PERAKENDE_DOVIZ>TL</PERAKENDE_DOVIZ>
        <PERAKENDE_FIYAT>0</PERAKENDE_FIYAT>
        <KALAN>0</KALAN>
        <OKUNAN_BARKOD>ESP12</OKUNAN_BARKOD>
        <BIRIM_KODU>AD</BIRIM_KODU>
        <KDV_TUTARI>0.00</KDV_TUTARI>
      </dsname>
      <dsname>
        <SIRANO>-5</SIRANO>
        <STOKKODU>ESP12</STOKKODU>
        <STOKADI>CHAİ TEA LATTE</STOKADI>
        <DIP_ISKONTO_TUTARI>0.00</DIP_ISKONTO_TUTARI>
        <BORC>1.00</BORC>
        <MIKTAR>1.000</MIKTAR>
        <FIYAT>1.0000</FIYAT>
        <ISKONTO_TUTARI>0.00</ISKONTO_TUTARI>
        <TUTAR>1.00</TUTAR>
        <BARKOD>810000000017</BARKOD>
        <FIYAT_TL>1.0000</FIYAT_TL>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT1>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT1>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT2>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT2>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT3>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT3>
        <PERAKENDE_DOVIZ>TL</PERAKENDE_DOVIZ>
        <PERAKENDE_FIYAT>0</PERAKENDE_FIYAT>
        <KALAN>0</KALAN>
        <OKUNAN_BARKOD>ESP12</OKUNAN_BARKOD>
        <BIRIM_KODU>AD</BIRIM_KODU>
        <KDV_TUTARI>0.00</KDV_TUTARI>
      </dsname>
      <dsname>
        <SIRANO>-6</SIRANO>
        <STOKKODU>ESP04</STOKKODU>
        <STOKADI>AMERİCANO</STOKADI>
        <DIP_ISKONTO_TUTARI>0.00</DIP_ISKONTO_TUTARI>
        <BORC>1.00</BORC>
        <MIKTAR>1.000</MIKTAR>
        <FIYAT>1.0000</FIYAT>
        <ISKONTO_TUTARI>0.00</ISKONTO_TUTARI>
        <TUTAR>1.00</TUTAR>
        <BARKOD>810000000009</BARKOD>
        <FIYAT_TL>1.0000</FIYAT_TL>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT1>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT1>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT2>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT2>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT3>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT3>
        <PERAKENDE_DOVIZ>TL</PERAKENDE_DOVIZ>
        <PERAKENDE_FIYAT>0</PERAKENDE_FIYAT>
        <KALAN>0</KALAN>
        <OKUNAN_BARKOD>ESP04</OKUNAN_BARKOD>
        <BIRIM_KODU>AD</BIRIM_KODU>
        <KDV_TUTARI>0.00</KDV_TUTARI>
      </dsname>
      <dsname>
        <SIRANO>-7</SIRANO>
        <STOKKODU>ESP09</STOKKODU>
        <STOKADI>CAPPUCCİNO</STOKADI>
        <DIP_ISKONTO_TUTARI>0.00</DIP_ISKONTO_TUTARI>
        <BORC>1.00</BORC>
        <MIKTAR>1.000</MIKTAR>
        <FIYAT>1.0000</FIYAT>
        <ISKONTO_TUTARI>0.00</ISKONTO_TUTARI>
        <TUTAR>1.00</TUTAR>
        <BARKOD>810000000014</BARKOD>
        <FIYAT_TL>1.0000</FIYAT_TL>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT1>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT1>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT2>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT2>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT3>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT3>
        <PERAKENDE_DOVIZ>TL</PERAKENDE_DOVIZ>
        <PERAKENDE_FIYAT>0</PERAKENDE_FIYAT>
        <KALAN>0</KALAN>
        <OKUNAN_BARKOD>ESP09</OKUNAN_BARKOD>
        <BIRIM_KODU>AD</BIRIM_KODU>
        <KDV_TUTARI>0.00</KDV_TUTARI>
      </dsname>
      <dsname>
        <SIRANO>-8</SIRANO>
        <STOKKODU>ESP08</STOKKODU>
        <STOKADI>CARAMEL MACCHİATO</STOKADI>
        <DIP_ISKONTO_TUTARI>0.00</DIP_ISKONTO_TUTARI>
        <BORC>1.00</BORC>
        <MIKTAR>1.000</MIKTAR>
        <FIYAT>1.0000</FIYAT>
        <ISKONTO_TUTARI>0.00</ISKONTO_TUTARI>
        <TUTAR>1.00</TUTAR>
        <BARKOD>810000000013</BARKOD>
        <FIYAT_TL>1.0000</FIYAT_TL>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT1>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT1>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT2>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT2>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT3>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT3>
        <PERAKENDE_DOVIZ>TL</PERAKENDE_DOVIZ>
        <PERAKENDE_FIYAT>0</PERAKENDE_FIYAT>
        <KALAN>0</KALAN>
        <OKUNAN_BARKOD>ESP08</OKUNAN_BARKOD>
        <BIRIM_KODU>AD</BIRIM_KODU>
        <KDV_TUTARI>0.00</KDV_TUTARI>
      </dsname>
      <dsname>
        <SIRANO>-9</SIRANO>
        <STOKKODU>ESP12</STOKKODU>
        <STOKADI>CHAİ TEA LATTE</STOKADI>
        <DIP_ISKONTO_TUTARI>0.00</DIP_ISKONTO_TUTARI>
        <BORC>1.00</BORC>
        <MIKTAR>1.000</MIKTAR>
        <FIYAT>1.0000</FIYAT>
        <ISKONTO_TUTARI>0.00</ISKONTO_TUTARI>
        <TUTAR>1.00</TUTAR>
        <BARKOD>810000000017</BARKOD>
        <FIYAT_TL>1.0000</FIYAT_TL>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT1>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT1>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT2>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT2>
        <DOVIZ_FIYAT3>0</DOVIZ_FIYAT3>
        <PERAKENDE_DOVIZ>TL</PERAKENDE_DOVIZ>
        <PERAKENDE_FIYAT>0</PERAKENDE_FIYAT>
        <KALAN>0</KALAN>
        <OKUNAN_BARKOD>ESP12</OKUNAN_BARKOD>
        <BIRIM_KODU>AD</BIRIM_KODU>
        <KDV_TUTARI>0.00</KDV_TUTARI>
      </dsname>
     
    </NewDataSet>
`

updateTable(xml)
/*
xml = `<root>
<dsname><stokadi>number 1</stokadi><borc>40</borc></dsname>
<dsname><stokadi>number 2</stokadi><borc>15</borc></dsname>
</root>`

setTimeout(function() {
  updateTable(xml)
}, 2000)

let xml2 = `<root>
<dsname><stokadi>number 2</stokadi><borc>15</borc></dsname>
</root>`

setTimeout(function() {
  updateTable(xml2)
}, 4000)
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>STOKADI</th>
      <th>BORC</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody id="tableBody">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In your code, you should have the `updateNeeded` and `updateTable` functions outside the `$(document).ready` block, and that should look like:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    //ajax call to load XML and parse it
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '01.xml',          
      dataType: 'xml',    
      success: function(xml) {
        updateTable(xml)
      }
    });
  }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: I try to add ode but its not working.Sorry i am new at jquery and js i try to run it but the problem is stokadi always undefined at this version.

Comment: Hi again.I added code succesfuly but problem is when you try to add same item its not working because of lenght.I have id every xml dsname child.what  we can check for control id

Comment: @EmreBirinci I thought that you didn't want to add the same item?

Comment: I mean when seller add 2 times same product its need to show.My problem is repeat xml everytime.For example: 3 product in screen but when i try to set interval everytime added to table like table going like +3 +6 +9 +12 i want to stop repeat.I need to check xml everytime because when seller finish the sell xml going to empty.When click the item data going to xml live.So i need to stop repeat but i need to re run function if some items added the seller screen

Comment: @EmreBirinci can you modify your question with some sample XML data that demonstrates the problem? That will make it easier for me to find a solution

Comment: @EmreBirinci I've updated the function in the answer to remove products from the table which are no longer in the XML. I put some timers in the code to make it easier to see what is happening.

Comment: I add seller screen at my question.At your first code there is no table repeat inside the problem is when seller add same item i mean 2x latte the second ones not showing at html table.Remove is no problem but result is same because item lenghts are same.I try t complete it from 2 days my brain is already death because of this and i must complete it tomorrow its really big problem for me.

Comment: @EmreBirinci will the products in the XML always be in the same order?

Comment: I upload the video about it.When seller ends sale the html table will remove.Its like customer info screen.

Comment: @EmreBirinci I've updated my answer to update whenever the table doesn't match the XML. Hopefully that will do what you want.

Comment: @EmreBirinci Note that Stackoverflow requires all questions to be self-contained. Linking to an external video does not meet that requirement.

Comment: Sorry about this.I didn't now it.

Comment: It's fine I just thought I'd let you know. Anyway I've edited my answer again...

Comment: Sorry.I know its a very lot ask but i edit my code after your answer.Not showing any info at table.I post my edit at answer i guess its really wrong.My brain stopped.I guess you using let xml codes for make xml at the page right ? thats why i do like this

Comment: @EmreBirinci the two functions `updateNeeded` and `updateTable` should be outside of the `$(document).ready` block. And your `success` function should just be `success: function(xml) { updateTable(xml) }`

Comment: i edit the page again nothing happened at this version.I slept just 4 hour from 2 day sorry for this edits :/